# JetBrains WebIDE: PHP variable type hinting?

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting, web-ide

Is there a way to hint WebIDE that a variable has some type?
I have to iterate an array of objects, and there's no auto-completion available.
This helps in ZendStudio:

```
/* @var ClassName $object */
```

I know there's a feature in JetBrains to declare an array of objects:

```
/**
 * @return ClassName[]
 */
```

But this works only with function's return type.

Comment: It works with arrays. Does it work with ArrayIterators which iterate over a specific type?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

`/* @var ClassName $object */` is a non-valid PHPDOC comment and is not parsed in the current version of Web IDE. Use double asterisks to make it work:

```
/** @var ClassName $object */
```

Also, you can annotate `$array` in `foreach($array as $var)` with `/** @var ClassName[] $array */` and `$var` type will be deduced automatically.

Comment: didn't know about the square brackets notation

Comment: Related question: My PHP class uses magic getter for a variable and I want to bind that getter variable to a Class object, any idea how to do that? As I cannot define the variable in my class.

Comment: Wow.. just googled for fun and really no hope that this will actually be a thing.. I never was so wrong in my life and I am happy that I was wrong! This feature is so cool, thanks! :)

Comment: Very relevant for $this->getUser() inside a controller in a Symfony app

Answer (score 35):

As already pointed out, PhpStorm will use regular phpdoc blocks:

```
/** @var ClassName $object */
```

However, since [2.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2011/05/phpstorm-2-1-available/) it also supports Netbeans/Eclipse/Zend [@var annotations](https://web.archive.org/web/20200921104605/https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/defining-a-variable-type-in-comment):

```
/* @var $object ClassName */
```

Please note the comment starts with `/*` rather than `/**` (thus it won't show up if you generate actual documentation with phpdoc). Also, the arguments are swapped, though PhpStorm accepts any order:

```
/* @var ClassName $object */
```

Last but not least, they can precede almost any arbitrary line of code (technically, phpdoc blocks are restricted to certain items).

---

**Edit:** as of 2019, Netbeans/Eclipse/Zend @var annotations seem to be mostly abandoned. NetBeans 11 no longer supports them and in general they aren't supported by other IDEs. I suggest to use the other syntax.

Comment: Last archive of the introduction of this annotation style on former Netbeans owner Oracle's blog: https://web.archive.org/web/20200921104605/https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/defining-a-variable-type-in-comment

Comment: @ReinState Answer updated, thank you!